# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column in 'field list' using Criteria and mapping annotation

Tags: mysql, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

i have criterias  to access result by

First Hibernate Dao is

```
AnswerText answersText = questionManager.getAnswerTextByAnswerIdAndLanguageId(answers.getAnswerId(), 1L);

@Override
    public AnswerText getAnswerTextByAnswerIdAndLanguageId(Number answerId,Number languageId) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AnswerText.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("answer.answerId", answerId));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("languageId", languageId));
        List<AnswerText> results = criteria.list();
        return (results !=null && !results.isEmpty()? results.get(0): null);
    }




Answers.java

@Entity  
@Table(name = "ANSWERS")
@Cacheable

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Answer {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")  
    private Long  answerId;

    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")  
    private Long      questionId;

    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATED")  
    private Timestamp   dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY_ID")  
    private Long      creatorId;

    @Column(name = "DATE_MODIFIED")  
    private Timestamp   dateModified;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY_ID")  
    private Long    modifierId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "answer" )
    private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>();

            //getters and setters


AnswerText.java

@Entity  
@Table(name = "ANSWERTEXT")
@Cacheable

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class AnswerText {

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT_ID")  
    private Long answerTextId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="answerId", insertable=false, updatable=false, 
                nullable=false)
    private Answer answer;

    @Column(name = "ANSWER_TEXT")  
    private String answerText;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGE_ID")  
    private Long languageId;

            //getters and setters
```

When i access the to fetch resultset, it shows below error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'answertext2_.answerId' in 'field list'
```

Then i changed to below in

AnswerText.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ANSWER_ID", nullable = false) 
    private Answer answer;
```

Answers.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "answer" )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<AnswerText> answerText = new HashSet<AnswerText>();
```

This produce no error But fetch results twice on calling

Second HibernateDao call is

```
List<Answer> answerList = questionManager.getAnswersByQuestionId(Long.parseLong("2"));
            System.out.println("answerList :"+answerList1.size());

    @Override
public ArrayList<Answer> getAnswersByQuestionId(Number questionId) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Answer.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("questionId", questionId));
    ArrayList<Answer> answerList = (ArrayList) criteria.list();
    return answerList;
}
```

Can Please anyone point me what is going wrong here. PLease help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have done right changing the JoinColumn-name.

Your multiple results in my opinion is bound to:

**FetchType.EAGER** and the selection of

> **FetchMode JOIN** As indicated you’ll have to worry about duplicated
>   results. On the other hand JOIN creates the least amount of queries.
>   In a high latency environment a single JOIN could be considerable
>   faster then multiple SELECTS. Keep in mind that joining too much data
>   could put a strain on the database.
>   from http://www.solidsyntax.be/2013/10/17/fetching-collections-hibernate/

With **FetchMode.SELECT** you would get the result like you want to have it.